# Android jar file compatibility linphone

Tags: java, android, eclipse, linphone

Issue with linphone SDK.

I downloaded linphone android sdk which contains jar and placed the jar in libs of my Project.

when i run the project,  console is showing error Multiple dex files define

```
[2015-10-15 17:07:48 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/linphone/BuildConfig;
[2015-10-15 17:07:48 - linphone-android] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/linphone/BuildConfig;
```

so i unchecked the Android Private Libs (Properties  --> Java Build Path --> Order & export)

Class is imported from the package in my project but when i run the project logcat is showing below error...

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/linphone/mediastream/Log;

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.linphone.mediastream.Log" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.linphone-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.linphone-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Help Me Please.. thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import all the `.so` files generated by the Makefile, the `.jar` library should not be enough.

Comment: Thank @Bhargav, I know that. This was actually meant to be an answer (something that helps solving a problem) since that's the way I managed to do what Sandy09 was trying to do.

Comment: Okay, @Andre, I have edited the post. Sorry for the earlier comment.